# Email can't be sent from yii2 application on cpanel

Tags: php, yii, cpanel, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

I have developed a yii2 application and deployed it in a CPanel on Bluehost. I created an email account in the CPanel to send emails using swiftmailer. When I use the email in localhost (my pc) it is working fine. however when I run it in CPanel it doesn't send the email even though the result is true and no error found in the logs. How can the hosted application send the emails? what configuration should be changed? I tried updating SPF records but it doesn't works. I checked the email restrictions and connect device details.

Sender domain for the project hosted in CPanel is a subdomain: api.mydomainname.com
the domain is hosted on the same server.

email configuration is as follows:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                //'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
                'host' => 'mail.mydomainname.com',
                'port' => '587',
                'username' => 'noreply@mydomainname.com',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
                'streamOptions' => [ 
                    'ssl' => [ 
                        'allow_self_signed' => true,
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    ],
                ]
            ],         
        ]
```

I tried updating SPF records but it doesn't works.
Changing the port to 25 & 465 and encryption to ssl. It fails to connect.

When I change the sender email(user@workdomain.co) and host (outlook.office365.com) it works fine.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you sure this is directly related to cPanel?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to change mail configuration in my project. I think there is something i need to update in the Cpanel configuration because i can use the same configuration in main-local.config file in my pc to send the email while it fails in the Cpanel. In the Cpanel I can use another email configuration for another host but it fails for the domain hosted in the Cpanel

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the host to mail.(main domain of my bluehost CPanel) and it worked